# Split a string by characters or position from the right and return two components

Tags: string-manipulation

If I have a string

```
MyString = "MyString"
```

what is the best way to split it by characters or positions from the **right**. My current solution is to break the string up into individual characters, get the total length and then use standard list manipulation

```
ComponentStringList = {{"M"}, {"y"}, {"S"}, {"t"}, {"r"}, {"i"}, \
{"n"}, {"g"}};
StringListLength = Length[ComponentStringList];
SplitPositionFromRight = 3;
Result = ComponentStringList[[1 ;; StringListLength - SplitPositionFromRight]];
StringJoin[ArrayFlatten[Result]]
```

This works, but it's ugly and long -- I'm sure there is a better way

Comment: No. Because `StringTake[MyString, -3]` will return the **last** three characters, I want to split the string by characters from the right. I'll take a look at `StringPart`.

Comment: @Moo `StringPart` is a good call, but `StringDrop` is shorter. Still, thanks for the point to `StringPart`, I'm sure it will come in handy one day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`StringDrop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringDrop.html):

```
StringDrop[MyString, -3]
```

> "MyStr"

Comment: knocks it out the park. Perfect.